# Is it possible to change a static constant from another file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, static

I' using a 3-rd party library. 
There is static constant somewhere in .h file.

```
static CGFloat const kJAButtonWidth = 60;
```

Is it possible to change its value from my file?

Comment: You need to get and study a book in the "C" language.

Comment: cant change const's but maybe define your own static variable that is initialized to that variables value? then you can change it freely

Comment: Can you link us to the library that you're using?

Comment: library is https://github.com/joseria/JASwipeCell